# Weekly Calendar View in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, calendar, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

So I'm wondering if there's a way using a recursive CTE, I can pull 7 day weeks at a time for every month in a year. Currently, for a monthly calendar view I'm using a recursive CTE that uses the startdate as an anchor and recurses until the enddate (I've pasted the proc below). This weekly view I'm trying to create is supposed to look similar to the one found in Microsoft Outlook's Calendar tab. Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Monthly View Proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Event].[Report_Event_Calendar_Month_sp]
    @start_cymd DATE = NULL ,
    @end_cymd DATE = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @StartDate DATE = @start_cymd ,
            @EndDate DATE = @end_cymd
    IF @StartDate IS NULL
        SET @StartDate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dd, GETDATE()) + 1, GETDATE()))
    IF @EndDate IS NULL
        SET @EndDate = CONVERT(DATE, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))

    ---First day of current month
    SET @StartDate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(s, 0, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @StartDate), 0)))
    ---First day to display on calendar
    SET @StartDate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) + 1, @StartDate))
    ---Last day of month
    SET @EndDate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(s, 0, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @start_cymd) + 1, 0)))
    ---Last day to display on calendar
    SET @EndDate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 6-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @EndDate), @EndDate))

    ;WITH Dates([Date])
          AS (
                SELECT @StartDate AS [Date]
                UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
                FROM Dates
                WHERE [Date] < @EndDate
              ) ,
          Events
          AS (
                SELECT EventDesc ,
                       Notes ,
                       start_cymd AS EventDate,
                       end_cymd
                FROM   [Event].Event_Description ED
                       INNER JOIN [Event].SQL_Team_Events SE ON ED.EventDesc_ID = SE.EventDesc_ID
             )
   ---Number the records based on the date, if multiple records have 
   ---the same date then they will be numbered the same. Used in 
   ---calculation to determine row record is to display 
    SELECT   [Order] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY d.[Date]) ,
   ---Date used in all calculations for date
             d.[Date] ,
   ---Generates matrix columns
             [WeekDay] = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.[Date]) ,
   ---Used to display day of month on calendar
             [Day] = DATEPART(DAY, d.[Date]) ,
   ---Used in some calculations for display
             [Month] = DATEPART(MONTH, d.[Date]) ,
             e.EventDesc ,
             e.Notes ,
             e.EventDate ,
             e.end_cymd 
    FROM     Dates d
             LEFT JOIN Events e ON d.[Date] = e.EventDate
   ---Set the maximum number of times the CTE 'Dates' can recurse
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100)

END
```

Comment: can you provide a desire output? Im not sure how you want handle each week when doesnt start on sunday/monday.

Comment: Based on the start date you input, so let's say the user inputs October 7th, the week view would display that week (October 4th - October 10th)

Comment: so what happen if imput October 3? will show `1-2-3` or `27-28-29-30-1-2-3`

Comment: I really not sure what is your desire output. And your query is TL:DR.

Comment: It would show 27-28-29-30-1-2-3.